# Swift 3 cannot recognize the macro function

Tags: swift3

I have a problem with the macro in swift 3. I tried to use the header file in swift project. I followed this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html). It generated the Bridging-Header.h file and I can import another header file. But, in the swift file, I only call the macro constants, but not the function. For example, the header file

```
#ifndef testHeader_h
#define testHeader_h

#if DEBUG
#define TEST_VALUE 111
#define TEST_STRING "Test string"
#endif

#if DEBUG
#define DLOG(fmt,...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA__ARGS__)
#else
#define DLOG(...)
#endif

#endif /* testHeader_h */
```

the .swift file,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtDisplay: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPush: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func setTextView(_ sender: UIButton) {
//        LogTrace("IN")
        DLOG();
        txtDisplay.text = TEST_STRING

    }
}
```

As you see, the UI only has the button and the textview. When we push the button, it write a log in the console and put the text in the textview. But, when I compile, it gets the error

```
ViewController.swift:29:9: Use of unresolved identifier 'DLOG'
```

I don't understand that, when I deleted line DLOG in swift file, it works and I can get the macro `TEST_STRING`. Why it does't recognize the macro function DLOG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> ## Complex Macros
>
> Complex macros are used in C and Objective-C but have no counterpart
> in Swift. Complex macros are macros that do not define constants,
> including parenthesized, function-like macros. You use complex macros
> in C and Objective-C to avoid type-checking constraints or to avoid
> retyping large amounts of boilerplate code. However, macros can make
> debugging and refactoring difficult. In Swift, you can use functions
> and generics to achieve the same results without any compromises.
> Therefore, the complex macros that are in C and Objective-C source
> files are not made available to your Swift code.

And the Objective-C to Swift migration guide suggests:

> Declare simple macros as global constants, and translate complex macros into functions.

Comment: Oh, many thanks! I got it. So, I just transfer complex macro in swift file.